# Removing stand-alone numbers from string in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

There are a lot of similar questions, but I have not found a solution for my problem. I have a data frame with the following structure/form:

```
   col_1
0  BULKA TARTA 500G KAJO 1
1  CUKIER KRYSZTAL 1KG KSC 4
2  KASZA JĘCZMIENNA 4*100G 2 0.92
3  LEWIATAN MAKARON WSTĄŻKA 1 0.89
```

However, I want to achieve the effect:

```
   col_1
0  BULKA TARTA 500G KAJO
1  CUKIER KRYSZTAL 1KG KSC
2  KASZA JĘCZMIENNA 4*100G
3  LEWIATAN MAKARON WSTĄŻKA
```

So I want to remove the independent natural and decimal numbers, but leave the numbers in the string with the letters.

I tried to use `df.col_1.str.isdigit().replace([True, False],[np.nan, df.col_1])` , but it only works on comparing the entire cell whether it is a number or not.

You have some ideas how to do it? Or maybe it would be good to break the column with spaces and then compare?

Comment: Sounds like you want regular expressions.

Comment: Updated my answer to also include a regex example. Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a function that tries to convert to float. If it fails we return True (not_float)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col_1" : ["BULKA TARTA 500G KAJO 1",
                              "CUKIER KRYSZTAL 1KG KSC 4",
                              "KASZA JĘCZMIENNA 4*100G 2 0.92",
                              "LEWIATAN MAKARON WSTĄŻKA 1 0.89"]})

def is_not_float(string):
    try:
        float(string)
        return False
    except ValueError:  # String is not a number
        return True

df["col_1"] = df["col_1"].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x.split(" ") if is_not_float(i)])

df
```

Or following the example of my fellow SO:ers. However this would treat 130. as a number.

```
df["col_1"] = (df["col_1"].apply(
    lambda x: [i for i in x.split(" ") if not i.replace(".","").isnumeric()]))
```

Returns

```
                          col_1
0    [BULKA, TARTA, 500G, KAJO]
1  [CUKIER, KRYSZTAL, 1KG, KSC]
2   [KASZA, JĘCZMIENNA, 4*100G]
3  [LEWIATAN, MAKARON, WSTĄŻKA]
```

Comment: This is my favorite solution. And how to use something like `' '.join(df2[i])` after each line, so that everything is connected again?

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski Sorry is that a question? What is df2 in this case?

Comment: Yes:) I introduced a new variable 'df2' instead `df["col_1"]`, and later `h=[]
for i in range(len(df2)):
    h.append(' '.join(df2[i]))
    g = "\n".join(h)
    
with open("C:\\Users\dell\\Desktop\\delikatesy\\wyczyszczone\\delikatesy_test1.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as of:
        of.write(g)`. I'm just learning, but I think it's easier to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure,

You could use a regex.

```
import re
df.col_1 = re.sub("\d+\.?\d+?", "",  df.col_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
def no_nums(col):
    return ' '.join(filter(lambda word:word.replace('.','').isdigit()==False, col.split()))
df.col_1.apply(no_nums)
```

This filters out words from each value which are completely made of digits,
And maybe contains a decimal point.
If you want to filter out numbers like `1,000`, simply add another `replace` for `','`